# Porting ROS to other Languages

Tags: ros, rospy, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suppose I wanted to write an implementation of the ROS paradigm for other languages.I notice that there is a complete implementation of ROS for Java, as well as Python, and I was thinking specifically about writing an implementation for C# in Mono and .NET. Is there a list of core features somewhere I would have to implement to get this off the ground? Are there any good resources and best practices I should look for before embarking on this project?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10956/porting-ros-to-other-languages/) by [Matt Klingensmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/942/matt-klingensmith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2011-08-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-19**:
I also want to write C# client for ROS, but I haven't found the way to do it. Can I have your msn or mail? If I can help you anything, I would like to share all my experiences. I have several month of ROS experiences.Now is working on navigation and cognitive.Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a basic introduction for [Client Libraries](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Client%20Libraries) also adressing the implementation of new client libraries.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2